# Are transfinite cell complexes the same as the usual cell complexes?

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal, considered as a set of the ordinals less than it. Aditionally suppose we have a function $h:\alpha+1 \to \mathbb N$. Suppose for each $i \leq \alpha$ we have a topological space $X_i$, and further that:

- If $i$ is a successor ordinal, then $X_i$ is obtained by attaching any number (cardinality) of $h(i)$-cells to $X_{i-1}$. I.e. $X_i$ is the pushout $\coprod_k D^{h(i)} \leftarrow \coprod_k S^{h(i)-1} \to X_{i-1}$, with $k$ being any cardinal.
- If $i$ is a limit ordinal, then $X_i$ is the colimit of $X_{j < i}$. I.e. $X_i=\bigcup_{j < i} X_j$ with the weak topology.

Under this assumptions, we say that $X_\alpha$ is a cell complex over $X_0$ of height $\alpha$. (Here $X_0$ can be any space).

My question is: is any cell complex over $X_0$ of height $\alpha$ homeomorphic to a cell complex over $X_0$ of height $\omega$?

---

This is motivated by the fact that the references I've read don't specify if $\alpha$ must be $\omega$, Other places mention transfiniteness though don't mention the limit case, like this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23415/cw-structure-on-spaces-obtained-by-attaching-cells-wildly). My hope is that maybe the chosen $\alpha$ doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a transfinite cell complex, and define a relation $\prec$ on the set $C$ of (open) cells of $X$ where $a\prec b$ if the image of the attaching map for $b$ intersects $a$.  For any cell $b$, there are only finitely many $a$ such that $a\prec b$, since the image of the attaching map for $b$ is compact (and by the usual argument, a compact subset of a transfinite cell complex can only intersect finitely many open cells).  Also, $\prec$ is a well-founded relation, since $a\prec b$ means that $a$ is attached in an earlier stage of the transfinite construction than $b$ is.

Now consider the rank function $r:C\to Ord$ of this well-founded relation $\prec$, i.e. $r(b)=\sup\{r(a)+1:a\prec b\}$.  Since for any $b$ there are only finitely many $a$ such that $a\prec b$, an easy induction shows that in fact $r(b)$ is finite for all $b$.  Now note that we could instead construct $X$ by starting with $X_0$ and attaching all of the cells of rank $0$, then all the cells of rank $1$, and so on.  This constructs $X$ as a cell complex over $X_0$ of height $\omega$.

Comment: Nice argument! Regarding the last step, I think attaching all the cells of rank $n$ may not be possible to do in a finite number of steps, since attaching $m$-cells takes a single step in height. For example, consider attaching countable points $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ and attaching an $i$-sphere to each point $x_i$. Then attaching all the cells of rank 2 will have height $\omega$, so that if there was any cell attachment of rank 3, your construction would be of height $\omega + 1$.

Comment: This particular case can be circumvented by doing depth first instead of breath first. I think a similar interleaving technique could be adapted for the general case, but I'm not sure of this.

Comment: Indeed, interleaving solves this. Attach as much $n$-cells as possible in the following order: $0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, \dots, 4, 0, \dots$. Since each specific cell has finite rank and depends on a finite number of finite rank cells, this will eventually cover every cell.

Comment: Oh, I missed that your definition requires all the cells attached in a single step to have the same dimension.  That seems like a pretty arbitrary requirement if you aren't requiring the cells to be attached in order of dimension (as in a CW-complex).

Comment: Another way to achieve that besides interleaving is to tweak the definition of the rank function.  For instance, you can instead define $r(b)=\max(\sup\{r(a)+1:a\prec b\},\dim b)$ to guarantee that a cell of rank $n$ has dimension at most $n$, so you can attach all the cells of each rank grouped by dimension in finitely many steps.